# Waterproofing flat balcony over a shed

Tags: floor, waterproofing, exterior, subfloor, decking

I have a kid's club house built over a shed part of it exposed as a balcony with flat floor no roof over it . The old floor was an OSB flooring badly damaged with water, so I replaced it with a new one(pic attached). But I am not sure how to waterproof it and looking for some advice. I am not looking for a state of the art solution, but a simple basic way (read economical) which works. To summarize

1. Do I need a waterproof tarp or membrane and then a pressure treated plywood over it ? Or is there another way to waterproof it? Someone suggested putting a concrete sheet and then add outdoor tiles (similar to what is done in bathroom), but not sure.
2. Is there an easy way to create a slight slope without removing the OSB?
   [image]

Comment: “A slight slope” - you could have done that with tapered planks on the supports before laying the new floor. A 1/4” from house to edge would have helped. May be worth lufting the floor and doing it now before you continue. Some drain holes or gap as well.

Comment: If you raise a slope you'll have an issue at and with the door; it appears to swing outwards. Also, consider the siding; done properly you would have a flashing under the siding and overlapping the sloped floor...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it so instead of "raising a slope" as you put it lower the other end... use a tool called a planer.

Comment: @SolarMike Yup, but OP qualified that it must be "easy"... Practically nothing is ever easy... sigh

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for suggestions and I may try to use the planer to do something as you suggested. But my main concern about waterproofing  still remains. Any advice there?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it You are right about the door. But its not only the door, but the room's wall as well. The subfloor slides underneath, so, there is no way I can raise that end unless I take out everything. (and thats what I meant by 'easy'. I am fine with labor intensive work as long as it doesn't require technical expertise). Any advice on making it waterproof ?